# Telegram Bot with multi-stage menu without sending messages

Tags: python, bots, telegram-bot

Can somebody help, I cant understand how can I do my bot with two menus.
first - is "short menu" where you press the button and its open "long menu" with all functions
second - in "long menu" menu where I have all functions and the button "Back to Menu".
I cant understnand how to make the button "Back to Menu" that go back me to the "short menu"
help me  please. And the Main -- the clicking on buttons should not send a message to the user

```
def telegram():

    with open("madata") as f3:
        info = yaml.safe_load(f3)
        token = mytoken
    bot = Bot(token=token)
    dp = Dispatcher(bot)

#greeting message, pin this message in private chat
    @dp.message_handler(commands=['start'])
    async def greeting(message: types.Message):
        chat_id = message.chat.id
        msg = '''hello friend'''
    
# body of  keyboard
        small_function = ReplyKeyboardMarkup(
            keyboard = [
                [
                    KeyboardButton(text="show functions", callback_data='open menu all functions')
                ]
            ],
            resize_keyboard=True
        )
        all_functions = ReplyKeyboardMarkup(
            keyboard = [
                [
                    KeyboardButton(text="function 1", callback_data='do function1')
                ],
                [
                    KeyboardButton(text="function 2", callback_data='do function2')
                ],
                [
                    KeyboardButton(text="back to menu", callback_data=' open menu small_function')
                ],
            ],
            resize_keyboard=True
        )          

    #insert my keyboard
        sent_message = await bot.send_message(chat_id=chat_id, text=msg,parse_mode = "Markdown", reply_markup=small_function)
        print(sent_message.message_id)

    @bot.callback_query_handler(func=lambda call: True)
    async def answer(call):
```